# alternative solutions for Hadoop/Hive distributed-cache for handling very large dictionary file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, distributed-cache

We are creating a dictionary like application on Hadoop and Hive. 
The general process is batch-scanning billion of log data (e.g. words) against a big fixed dictionary (about 100G, like a multiple language WordNet dictionary).

We already have a single machine version of the java application (let's call this "singleApp") to query this dictionary. We currently could not modify either this java application or the dictionary file, thus we could not re-design and re-write a complete new MapReduce application. We need use this single machine version Java Application as the building block to extend it to a MapReduce version.

Currently, we are able to create a MapReduce application by calling this "singleApp" and pass a subset of dictionary (e.g. 1G dictionary) using distributed-cache. However, if we use the full dictionary (100G), the app is very very slow to start. Furthermore, we really want to install these dictionaries into the Hadoop cluster without calling it each time using -file or distributed cache options.

We tried to copy the dictionary files directly into local disks in slave nodes and pointing the java app to it, but it could not find the dictionary. Any documents on what need to be done if we want to debug more on this approach?

Any suggestions on what should be the best practice/process for us to handle situations like this (very large dictionary files, and prefer to keep the dictionary files installed all the time)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Hadoop for 100GB of data. You can use your distributed cache as a processing platform as well.

Consider your distributed cache as an In-Memory Data Grid.

Try TayzGrid an [Open Source In-Memory DataGrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/) with a [MapReduce](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/big-data-analytics.html) usecase such as yours.

```
public class ProductAnalysisMapper implements 
                             com.alachisoft.tayzgrid.runtime.mapreduce.Mapper {

    @Override
    public void map(Object ikey, Object ivalue, OutputMap omap) 
    {
          //This line emits value count to the map.
          omap.emit(ivalue, 1);
    }
}

public class ProductAnalysisReducer implements
                      com.alachisoft.tayzgrid.runtime.mapreduce.Reducer {

    public ProductAnalysisReducer(Object k) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void reduce(Object iv) { /* ... */ }

    @Override
    public void finishReduce(KeyValuePair kvp) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Basit, thanks for the help. Our input data could be 10TB+, and the dictionary data is 100G+.  My concern is the performance of distributed-cache if we put this 100G+ dict file into distributed-cache.

Comment: You load 100G+ data in the cache right ? not 10TB+.

Comment: And i have seen caches running a cluster of 6 with 200GB of RAM each :)

Comment: hi, Basit, thanks for sharing the experience. I'll test that out.